# Work with an uploaded file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need to create a custom web control which will be a part of a class library. This custom web control implements the upload functionality. I have implemented this with a web user control where I have a fixed path to a page in the web project where the upload of files take place and it works just fine.

The created control in this class library is used in the web project. How do I post the uploaded file to a page, say SomeClass.cs, in the class library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the file?  Open it and process input?

Comment: First, I need to create a Custom Web control which acts like an upload control .Now this control will be a part of the seperate dll which will then be accessed in a web project . Now this Custom web control i create works like this .The User is shown with a image and click of the image the file open dialog box is opened . This on select of a file gets directed to a aspx page where it gets saved . Now i want this uploading functionality that whatever happens in the redirect to the page to be done with in my Custom web control .How do i go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [file upload control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) to post the file to a code-behind file.

Comment: Its like this i create a Custom Control which is a cs file not an ascx or an aspx file this custom control is not a part of the WebProject . Its a class library contains only cs files . What should happen when this control is used in the web project is the file select dialog opens up ,user selects a file on select it should probably go to another page in the Class Library which could be a aspx or cs where i access the file by Request.Files and then save it ?????

Answer (score 1):

Pass the system path as a string overload?

```
string systemPathToFile = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + Path.Filename(fuFileUpload.Filename));
```